# Iterating over deeply Nested JSON

Tags: javascript, json, loops

Given that I have a large JSON as follows

```json
{
  "tab": [
    {
      "children": [
        {
          "children": [
            {
              "text": "some_string",
              "href": "some_href",
              "id": "inner_child_1"
            },
            {
              "text": "some_string",
              "href": "some_href",
              "id": "inner_child_2"
            }
          ],
          "text": "some_string",
          "href": "some_href",
          "id": "first_child"
        },
        {
          "children": [
            {
              "children": [
                {
                  "children": [
                    {
                      "text": "some_string",
                      "href": "some_href",
                      "id": "more_1"
                    },
                    {
                      "text": "some_string",
                      "href": "some_href",
                      "id": "more_2"
                    }
                  ],
                  "text": "some_string",
                  "href": "some_href",
                  "id": "inner_1"
                },
                {
                  "text": "some_string",
                  "href": "some_href",
                  "id": "inner_2"
                }
              ],
              "text": "some_string",
              "href": "some_href",
              "id": "inner_first_child"
            },
            {
              "text": "some_string",
              "href": "some_href",
              "id": "inner_second_child"
            }
          ],
          "text": "some_string",
          "href": "some_href",
          "id": "second_child"
        }
      ],
      "text": "some_string",
      "href": "some_href",
      "id": "root_folder"
    }
  ]
}
```

The nesting could go on up to multiple levels

The end goal is to iterate over the JSON and create folders with the IDs specified.

If an object has a children's array create a parent folder with Id and loop on children, if any entry in children's array has a children's array nested then create another subfolder and continue till there are no children's array is found. If there are no children continue with the next iteration.

The final folder structure might be as follows:

```
|--root_folder
    |-- first_child
        |-- inner_child_1
        |-- inner_child_2
    |-- second_child
        |-- inner_first_child
            |-- inner_1
                |-- more_1
                |-- more_2
            |-- inner_2
        |-- inner_second_child
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to do it in the best possible way to achieve this?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. ***Do some research***, [search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+iterate+nested+object+site:stackoverflow.com); if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
function parseData(obj, parent)
{
  const item = document.createElement("li"),
        a = document.createElement("a");

  a.href = obj.href;
  a.textContent = obj.text + " (id: " + obj.id + ")";
  item.appendChild(a);

  if (!obj.children)
    item.id = obj.id;

  parent.appendChild(item);

  if (obj.children)
  {
    const folder = document.createElement("ul");
    folder.id = obj.id;
    for(let i = 0; i < obj.children.length; i++)
      parseData(obj.children[i], folder); // loop through items inside folder

    parent.appendChild(folder);
  }
}

const data = {
  "tab": [
    {
      "children": [
        {
          "children": [
            {
              "text": "some_string",
              "href": "some_href",
              "id": "inner_child_1"
            },
            {
              "text": "some_string",
              "href": "some_href",
              "id": "inner_child_2"
            }
          ],
          "text": "some_string",
          "href": "some_href",
          "id": "first_child"
        },
        {
          "children": [
            {
              "children": [
                {
                  "children": [
                    {
                      "text": "some_string",
                      "href": "some_href",
                      "id": "more_1"
                    },
                    {
                      "text": "some_string",
                      "href": "some_href",
                      "id": "more_2"
                    }
                  ],
                  "text": "some_string",
                  "href": "some_href",
                  "id": "inner_1"
                },
                {
                  "text": "some_string",
                  "href": "some_href",
                  "id": "inner_2"
                }
              ],
              "text": "some_string",
              "href": "some_href",
              "id": "inner_first_child"
            },
            {
              "text": "some_string",
              "href": "some_href",
              "id": "inner_second_child"
            }
          ],
          "text": "some_string",
          "href": "some_href",
          "id": "second_child"
        }
      ],
      "text": "some_string",
      "href": "some_href",
      "id": "root_folder"
    }
  ]
};

for(let i = 0; i < data.tab.length; i++)
  parseData(data.tab[i], document.getElementById("main"));
```

```html
<ul id="main"></ul>
```